# to change csv file format and read one row with key value of csv

Tags: php, arrays, csv, delimiter, file-read

I have got a csv file, this csv file does not has a comma(,) among values but it has a  cap (^) symbol. 
I need to do two things now. 
1. To change this cap and get comma after each value from csv. 
2. I need to read one whole csv file that has almost 37 columns into once row of array along with first column as the key of array.

These both things have to be done using php.

I am trying through online exmaples like

```
function csv_to_array($filename='mycsv.csv', $delimiter=',')
{
    if(!file_exists($filename) || !is_readable($filename))
        return FALSE;

    $header = NULL;
    $data = array();
    if (($handle = fopen('mycsv.csv', 'r')) !== FALSE)
    {
        while (($row = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, $delimiter)) !== FALSE)
        {
            if(!$header)
                $header = $row;
            else
                $data[] = array_combine($header, $row);
        }
        fclose($handle);
    }
    return $data;
}
```

The thing I am confused is my actual csv  file is "abc"^"def"^" so abc is one value and def is another and both are separated by ^ how can I say first remove ^ take whole string start from " and end at " and add a comma.

[image]

I want something like this with array

Comment: What have you tried so far with php? Any code?

Comment: [`fgetcsv()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) allows you to specify the separator character.

Comment: _"along with first column as the key of array"_ Do you mean the first _row_? First column as key doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Now kindly look at the code #BenRoob

Comment: Now kindly look at the image what I want with array #Alex Howansky

Comment: _"how can I remove ^ and add a comma"_ You don't have to. Just specify `^` as `$delimiter` in the arguments passed to `csv_to_array()` and `fgetcsv()` will split on `^` instead of `,`.

Comment: Could you please give me a small code example to do this? Alex

Comment: i think you need to add more examples. You refer to abc^def and something more in the line. But the result should be an array with several numbers and Choice 1?